# Simple Question Regarding the Limit of An Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have encountered the following problem:

> Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1{\cos^n\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}}\Bigr)\,dx=0$

I first tried to turn the integral itself into a geometric series that led to the integral, that was obviously an idiotic decision. Then I tried to break down $\cos(1/x)$ into Taylor Series, however the restriction of the $n$th power prevented me from further progress. I decided to follow proof by intuition to see if I can come up with a formula for this sequence, however the case for $n=1$ is a divergent. The case for $n=2$ is fortunately convergent, but I think there's something very simple that I am just missing on this problem.

What am I missing? Is there an $n$th term formula for the integral only above?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you heard of the dominated convergence theorem?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 2):

$|\cos^{n}(1/x)|<1$ for all $n$ and a.e. $x\in(0,1]$, now $|\cos^{n}(1/x)|\rightarrow 0$ for all such $x$ and hence by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\cos^{n}(1/x)dx=0$.

Comment: Did you mean $|\cos(1/x)| < 1?$ Because it is true that $|\cos^n(1/x)|<1$ but it's not clear how $|\cos^n(1/x)|\to 0$ follows from $|\cos^n(1/x)|<1.$

Comment: I wanted to mean both actually.

Comment: Now the trick is that for all $n$ and all such $x$ it is true, then put $n=1$ to get the basic one.